# How to add to a date with ifelse

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column for the date and a text column called Rule.
If the text in the Rule Column is "`Rule_1`" I want to add 3 years to the date in that row, but if "`Rule_2`" then two years.

```
Date        Rule     NewDate
2010-01-01  Rule_1   2013-01-01
2012-01-01  Rule_2   2014-01-01
2015-01-01  No_Rule  2015-01-01
```

I seem to have a problem with adding the year using `lubridate`

```
 ifelse(df$Rule=="Rule1",df$Date %m+% years(3),df$Date)
```

It converts the added date to a number which I think is the number of days from an origin (?1970).
However if I run the expression `df$Date %m+% years(3)` without ifelse then it works fine. What to do?

Comment: did any of the answers solve your issue? if so, please mark an answer as accepted or leave a comment otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using one `tidyverse` package (`lubridate`) how about `case_when` from `dplyr`?  It's a vectorized `if` - and basically allows you to avoid a bunch of nested `ifelse` statements if you have multiple conditions.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(NewDate_Demo = case_when(Rule == "Rule_1" ~ Date %m+% years(3),
                          Rule == "Rule_2" ~ Date %m+% years(2),
                          TRUE ~ Date))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Date       Rule    NewDate    NewDate_Demo
  <date>     <chr>   <date>     <date>      
1 2010-01-01 Rule_1  2013-01-01 2013-01-01  
2 2012-01-01 Rule_2  2014-01-01 2014-01-01  
3 2015-01-01 No_Rule 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
```

`dplyr` does also offer `if_else`, which has the same general syntax as `base::ifelse` but won't break with `lubridate`
https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/644

Answer (score 1):

The base ifelse function is not type stable. Rather make use if the dplyr implementation `if_else()`. This automatically checks and retains the desired output type.
From its documentation:

> Compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks that true and false are the same type. This strictness makes the output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# never mix up tidyverse and data.table but damn, fread() is awesome :D 
df <- data.table::fread("
Date        Rule     NewDate
2010-01-01  Rule_1   2013-01-01
2012-01-01  Rule_2   2014-01-01
2015-01-01  No_Rule  2015-01-01") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = c(1, 3), as_date)

# more type stable ifelse
dplyr::if_else(df$Rule=="Rule_1", df$Date %m+% years(3), df$Date)

# desired output with nested if_else
# faster than case_when()
dplyr::if_else(df$Rule=="Rule_1", df$Date %m+% years(3), 
               if_else(df$Rule=="Rule_2", df$Date %m+% years(2), df$Date))

# piped dplyr way
df %>% 
  mutate(desired_date = if_else(Rule == "Rule_1",
                                true = Date %m+% years(3), 
                                false = if_else(Rule == "Rule_2", 
                                                true = Date %m+% years(2),
                                                false = Date)))
```